# Are there any performance advantages or compile time improvements from hiding the implementation of a public function in a private function

Tags: swift, performance

For instance say I have a CarModel

```
struct CarModel: Codable {
    var numberPlate: String
    var vin: String
    var model: String
    var fuel: Double
    var position: Position
}
```

and I have a public method

```
extension CarModel {
    var fuelString: String {
        return fuelStringImplementation
    }
}
```

but instead of having the implementation in the public method I hide it behind a private method.

```
private extension CarModel {
    var fuelStringImplementation: String {
        if fuel == 0.0 {
            return "car_list_item_tank_empty".localizedString()
        }
        let fuelDouble = fuel*100
        let finalString = String(format: "car_list_item_tank_status".localizedString(), fuelDouble)
        return finalString
    }
}
```

And for cellForAtIndexPath I can hide the implmentation in a private method like this

```
private func collectionViewImplementation(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MainImageCollectionViewCell.className, for: indexPath)
    guard let model = viewModel.modelForIndex(index: indexPath.row) else {
        assertionFailure("model is nil")
        return cell
    }
    guard let mainImageCell = cell as? MainImageCollectionViewCell else {
        assertionFailure("cell is not type MainImageCollectionViewCell")
        return cell
    }
    mainImageCell.fill(with: model)
    return mainImageCell
}
```

Comment: Premature Optimization. I think you should focus on writing bug free code that is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: It might be premature optimisazation but I would still like to know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter if the method is private or public for performance advantage.
If we are talking about functions and performance improvement (not to mention to a body implementation of that function), we should look closer to the method dispatch type. There are some of them: dynamic, table and direct. And direct has the best performance, for example. 
It's a huge theme, so I suggest you to read some articles about it on web. Like this, for example, https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27.

Comment: Shouldn't dynamic be the worst?